# Using Hibernate's Restrictions.ilike() on a Timestamp

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jqgrid

I've been thinking it over, and I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible.

**User Perspective**:
There's a table of data, and one column contains a date. The user can type in a search term like `dec` and get all rows that occurred during December.

**Backend**: A jqGrid is used for displaying the table. It sends the entered search terms to the server. The server uses the code

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria( DetailedLogEntry.class );
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
MatchMode matchMode = MatchMode.ANYWHERE;
disjunction.add( Restrictions.ilike( searchKey.getField(), searchKey.getData(), matchMode ) );
cr.add( disjunction );
```

to apply the search terms, and where `DetailedLogEntry` contains a `Date` variable to represent the database's `TIMESTAMP`field.

Because `searchKey.getData()` returns a string, comparing it against a date object results in an empty set.

*So I guess the question is*...is it possible, preferbly through Hibernate, to apply a restriction against a `Date` object as if it were a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible.  You'd need to use `Restrictions.between()` and give it an upper and lower date values.  You could use `SimpleDateFormat` to convert from your `String` values to `Date` values and then perform the search?

If the user searched for Dec, would you expect all the log entries from December of every year to show up?  Can they type in :"1, Dec" and expect to see all the logs from the 1st December for every year?  If it is string matching on dates you are looking for, it might be easier to load all the data into your jqGrid and use javascript to filter the table based on the string formatted date values.

Comment: 1. Yes, that is expected behavior. They can of course provide more information than just `dec` to further narrow it down.

Comment: 2. We don't load all data into the jqgrid at once because, after a year's worth of data, it could be too much for the grid to deal with efficiently.

Comment: @JesseJ You'll either have to load all the data in the backend and filter it there, or turn the query into date queries, but that could get quite cumbersome.